# Cannot broadcast the table that is larger than 8GB: 25GB

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My problem is that the table I am broadcasting has a size of 3GB but the error outputs a table size of 25GB.

I have seen in the source code that the datasize is calculated depending on the relation type:  https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/087082254170e46d4162a47fa9691cc298e08afe/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/BroadcastExchangeExec.scala#L150

Does it mean that the 3GB real size is not taken into account when performing a broadcast join?

Traceback:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot broadcast the table that is larger than 8GB: 25 GB
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$exchange$BroadcastExchangeExec$$doComputeRelation(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anon$1.doCompute(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anon$1.doCompute(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.AsyncDriverOperation.$anonfun$compute$1(AsyncDriverOperation.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.AsyncDriverOperation.compute(AsyncDriverOperation.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.AsyncDriverOperation.$anonfun$computeFuture$1(AsyncDriverOperation.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$1(SQLExecution.scala:275)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: How do you know that the size of a broadcast relation is 3GB?

Comment: Do you see a difference in behavior if you ran: ANALYZE TABLE <table_name> COMPUTE STATISTICS
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-aux-analyze-table.html